# Perl: Subroutines first argument is not the class

Tags: perl, subroutine

I'm relatively new to Perl so bear with me.

My sub getGenes calls getFeaturesByGeneName in the class SequenceModule. The first loop runs fine however in the second loop it tries to invoke get_SeqFeatures (a BioPerl sub) on the string $name meaning that it skips my $self = shift.

What am I missing?

```
sub getGenes
{
    my @names = shift;
    my $genome = shift;
    my @cds;

    foreach my $name (@names)
    {
        my $feat = SequenceModule -> getFeatureByGeneName($genome, $name);
        push (@cds, $feat);
    }

    return @cds;
}
```

...

```
sub getFeatureByGeneName
{
    my $self = shift;

    my $seq = shift;
    my $name = shift;

    my @cds = $seq -> get_SeqFeatures("CDS");

    ...
}
```

Comment: Please clarify. You only show one loop. What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: Also, how do you call `getGenes`?

Comment: `my @names = shift;` looks fishy; it'll only ever have one element. You probably want something more along the lines of `my ($genome, @names) = @_;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Speculation: you called `getGenes` with several names:

```
getGenes(('name1', 'name2'), $genome);
```

List don't nest in Perl, so the arguments are flattened:

```
getGenes('name1', 'name2', $genome);
```

`shift` can't return more than one element. Therefore,

```
my @names = shift;
```

is equivalent to

```
my @names;
$names[0] = shift;
```

The second name is still in `@_`, so it goes to `$genome`:

```
my $genome = shift;
```

If you need to pass a list to a sub, make it the last argument, or send a reference:

```
sub getGenes {
    my $genome = shift;
    my @names = @_;
}
getGenes($genome, 'name1', 'name2');

# OR

sub getGenes {
    my $names = shift;
    my $genome = shift;
    for my $name (@$names) {  # dereference
        ...
    }
}
getGenes(['name1', 'name2'], $genome);
```

Comment: I passed the list as the last argument and it works. Thanks alot.